# Spanish version of "not applicable"

Tags: traducción

What is the Spanish version of *not applicable*? I'm mostly concerned if the language has an abbreviation for *not applicable* like in English, "n/a."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We use the direct translation *no aplicable*, or the equivalent verbal construction *no aplica* (though it should probably be *no se aplica*).

If you read the dictionary, the third meaning of [*aplicar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3CjZzQU) is:

> 3. tr. Referir a un caso particular lo que se ha dicho en general, o a un individuo lo que se ha dicho de otro.

As you can see, this meaning is good in our case. You have a general characteristic, but you cannot apply it to some particular case, so you write *n/a*.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility is **no procede**

Answer (score 2):

As abbreviation sometimes you can see "**N/A**" (*No Aplica*).

As a word, it can be used ***Inaplicable*** which literally means "Not applicable".

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility may be **no corresponde**.

> **[corresponder](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AyxqUHu)**
>
> De co- y responder.
>
> 4. intr. Dicho de un elemento de un conjunto, colección, serie o sistema: Tener relación, realmente existente o convencionalmente establecida, con un elemento de otro.

Example: when asking "*¿Está usted embarazada?*", an answer may be "*No corresponde*", implying that "*si es usted hombre no le corresponde responderla*".